# Can't modify table column character set in Oracle

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, alter-table

I want to change character set so I used code as below:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_MST CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET sjis;
```

But I got error looks like this:

```
Error starting at line : 3 in command -
ALTER TABLE MY_MST CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET sjis
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
```

I also tried `ALTER TABLE MY_MST MODIFY ....`, same error, what can I do? I am working in Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Traditional question in such cases: Where in the Oracle documentation did you find the CONVERT option to ALTER TABLE? Where did you get the idea that you can selectively change the character set of one column in one table?

Comment: Sorry, I just found oracle here  `https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.0-en/alter-table.html`, but I didn't find its for mysql....:( by the way, what can I do next?